# What does quotient map $\pi: S^p\times S^q\to S^p \wedge S^q$ induce in homology?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I have a quotient map $\pi: S^p\times S^q\to S^p \wedge S^q\cong S^{p+q}$ and it would be useful for me to know, what $\pi_*: H_{p+q}( S^p\times S^q;\mathbb{Z})\to H_{p+q}(S^{p+q}; \mathbb{Z})$ looks like. I hope that it is an isomorphism, but I am not sure about that. Is it? How to prove/disprove that?

Thank you.

Comment: Since $\pi$ is a homeomorphism $(S^p-pt)\times(S^q-pt)$ to $S^{p+q}-pt$ you have the isomorphism.

Comment: Can you elaborate on that? I kinda agree that it is a homeomorphism , but how is it even connected to $\pi_*$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most natural way is cellular homology. $S^m$ has a CW-structure with one $0$-cell and one $m$-cell. Then $S^p\times S^q$ has cells $e_0 \times f_0, e_p \times f_0, e_0 \times f_q, e_p \times f_q,$ where $e_i, f_i$ are the corresponding cells of $S^p$ and $S^q.$ $S^{p+q}$ has one cells $c_0$ and $c_{p+q}.$ $H_{p+q}( S^p\times S^q;\mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $[e_p \times f_p]$, and $H_{p+q}(S^{p+q}; \mathbb{Z})$ is generated by $[c_{p+q}].$ What $\pi$ does is it factors out $e_p \times f_0$ and $e_0 \times f_q$ and sends $e_p \times f_q$ homeomorphically to $c_{p+q},$ so $\pi_*$ is an isomorphism.

Comment: Could you give some more details on the last sentence? Ok, $\pi$ does really send top cell to the top cell homeomorphically, I agree with that, but how does it imply that $\pi_*$ is an isomorphism? I don't really get how to work with induced maps in cellular homology...

Comment: @Haldot It works in the most direct way: to find where a cellular map $f: X \to Y$ sends a cell $\sigma \in C^\text{cell}_n(X),$ you for any $\tau \in C^\text{cell}_n(Y)$ calculate the degree of the map $S^n \xrightarrow{\sigma} X_n/X_{n-1} = \bigvee S^n \to Y_n/Y_{n-1} = \bigvee S^n \xrightarrow{proj_{\tau}} S^n$ . This number will be the coefficient in front of $\tau$ in $f_\# (\sigma).$

Comment: What is the first map in the composition? I mean the map $S^n\to X_n/X_{n-1}$. Is it like inclusion of $S^n=\sigma / \partial \sigma$ to the wedge? If it is, then the degree of composition is 1, because all maps are basically identities, right? Also, last question, where did you get this way of finding homomorphisms induced by cellular maps from? Hatcher does not even mention it. And thank you a lot.

Comment: @Haldot You can think of it as an inclusion corresponding to $\sigma$. The degree of the composition can be anything because of the middle map between wedges, which encapsulates the information about how $f$ works.

Comment: @Haldot It's strange if it's not in Hatcher. Well, there definitely is a proof in §13 of Homotopical Topology by Fomenko/Fuchs. This basically follows from the definition of $ C^\text{cell}_n(X)$ as $H_n(X_n, X_{n-1}).$

Comment: Yeah, I mean, in this particular case degree is 1 since the middle map is a homeomorphism (since $f$ maps top cell to top cell homeomorphically and these $S^n$'s are made out of these cells), right? Thanks for the reference, btw

Comment: @Haldot Exactly.